# Lvalue references for const pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, lvalue

Consider the following:

`1) const char* const`

Above, we are saying that there is a constant pointer (i.e. the pointer itself cannot be modified) pointing to a constant character (i.e. the *actual* char it is pointing to is const)

How about here:

`2) const char*&`

In the above, are saying that it is a `non-const` lvalue reference pointing to a `const char*`, or is it a `const` lvalue reference pointing to a `char*`?

How about here:

`3) const char* const&`

`non-const` lvalue reference pointing to a `const char* const`, a `const` lvalue reference pointing to a `char* const`, or a `const` lvalue reference pointing to a `const char*`?

Someone explain, please.

Comment: You can't have `const` l-value references, references are const by nature. By elimination, that gives the answer for each of the declarations.

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Comment: A reference doesn't have a `const` modifier distinct from the type it refers to. A pointer's second `const` modifier means you can't change *which* object it points to, but that is already true for references. A statement like *"non-const lvalue reference pointing to a `const char* const`"* doesn't make sense for C++ because it has every possible `const`, there is no perspective by which it could be considered non-`const`.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks.

Comment: The C language does not have references as a feature. That language tag is not appropriate for this question.

Comment: The usual trick is to read declaration backward to understand const...  `char const * const ` would read as const pointer to const char. `const char` and `char const` are synonymous. The first way is more widely used but some people prefer to use `char const` as it works best when reading backward.